# Use an array in foreach controllerin JMeter

Tags: jmeter

From the previous postprocesser I have an array (i.e. `UUIDCollector` which has around 2K UUID),

And I have put that array with
`vars.putObject("UUID_List", resultStudyUUIDCollector);`

Example of the array

```
[
    "f439d9bb-487b-4a46-b5aa-1013d8de464a",
    "6656dae1-159a-4062-9cbb-5382d5202cd8",
    "197650ca-d8fc-451d-9332-50d801b5c426",
    "ac7adabd-8040-498b-87ed-9c69d678ad49"....]
```

I want to pass these UUID to next URL call, but I am getting error

```
2023-06-11 16:25:52,482 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script169$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [f439d9bb-487b-4a46-b5aa-1013d8de464a]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, int), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
```

Configuration for JMeter,

Code for Processing the UUID's,

```
def UUID_List = vars.getObject("UUID_List");

log.info('Total Number of UUID: ' + UUID_List.size())

UUID_List.each {    myListItem, int index -> 
    vars.put('json_'+ (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(myListItem).toPrettyString())
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your "array" in the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured like in your screenshot you need to create the relevant [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) beforehand in form of:

```
json_1=f439d9bb-487b-4a46-b5aa-1013d8de464a
json_2=6656dae1-159a-4062-9cbb-5382d5202cd8
etc.
```

in order to do this you need to add the following line to the place where you create your "array"

```
1.upto(UUID_List.size(),{ vars.put('json_' + it, UUID_List.get(it - 1))})
```

then you will be able to refer the consecutive values inside the ForEach Controller as `${json}` where required.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see issue with you code, but minor changes to your code also works,

```
def UUID_List = vars.getObject("UUID_List");

log.info('Total Number of UUID: ' + UUID_List.size())

UUID_List.eachWithIndex {    myListItem, index -> 
    vars.put('json_'+ (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(myListItem).toPrettyString())
}
```